# Assign value to register

Tags: assembly

i'm having some problems rewriting some ASM code.
Atm the following code

```
FLD DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+20]
FDIV DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+28]
FSTP QWORD PTR SS:[ESP]
```

Where [ESP+20] contains a value from 1 to 10, and [ESP+28] is 30.

Now, i'm trying to rewrite this code, to skip the division and just assign a static value, but it does not seems to work for some reason, it just outputs "0". I'm doing the following:

```
MOV DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+28], 0A
FSTP QWORD PTR SS:[ESP]
```

I'm still pretty new at this assembly stuff, so i'm probably doing something wrong. 
Anyone here can point me in the right direction? I'd really appreciate it!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see

```
FSTP QWORD PTR SS:[ESP]
```

stores the floating point value that is on top of the FP stack into the address specified, and pops it off.

So for that to work you must first have loaded the constant onto the FP stack.

So you need to do something like this first:

```
MOV DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+28], 0A
FLD DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+28]
```

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. However the "MOV DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+28], 0A" does not seem to work, as it just outputs 1. Is there another way to load the constant onto the FP stack, which might work? Thanks again

Comment: Sorry - I wasn't paying close attention to what you are actually trying to accomplish here. To load an integer value onto the FP stack as a floating point value, you need to use the `FILD` instruction, not `FLD`. `FLD` assumes that the source is already an FP value.

Comment: Ah ok thanks, will keep that in mind till next time. Had someone help me do a DLL detour and rewrite the entire method for this one instead :-)